# Eclipse : Target "Unknown" in android device chooser

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am using Samsung Galaxy SIV. When I try to select it in the 'Android device chooser', Eclipse recognize as a Samsung  Galaxy SIV but in target it does not recognize. It says target "unknown". Because of this problem, I can't choose the phone as the Android device.

How can I get Eclipse to recognize the target ?

Comment: Which OS u are using?

Comment: i am using windows 8.

Comment: You should install driver for that device. Did you?

Comment: did you enable debugging options in your phone?

Comment: well, i restarted phone and laptop and it works fine now. i dont know where it went wrong first.

Comment: Rebooting the phone worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For Completeness: (Windows)

1) **Enable USB debugging on your device.**

On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under **Settings > Applications > Development.**
On Android **4.0** and newer, it's in **Settings > Developer** options.

Note: On Android **4.2** and **newer**, Developer options is **hidden by default**. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

2) **Restart your Phone**

When you have done this, still there will be "unknown" listed under target, from here, just restart your phone and as soon it is started, it will ask if you want to use this pc for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The first time your PC tries to connect with your device (after set up OEM USB driver), your device will ask if trust this pc or portal whatever. Make sure your answer yes on your device

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, first check your project property. Go to ANDROID tab -> select proper target.
Second in your AndroidManifest.xml file change the "android:minSdkVersion" & "android:targetSdkVersion" to what your android phone supports.

Answer (score 0):

For any future onlookers of this issue, I found that I needed to uncheck the debugger option and recheck it. After doing that, the popup showed for trusting my computer. I said always trust and hit okay and everything worked.